# In Angular 8 Update component that has already been instantiated previously

Tags: angular

I have performed a wrong database query because there was still nothing in localStorage, how can I update the component to re-query after login? 
I use the localstorage to get the id and make a BBDD call, but since the component has already been loaded the call is not made again.
I'm learning to use angular

```js
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User = new User();
  constructor(private authService:AuthService,private router:Router,private userService:UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUser();
    
  }

  getUser(){
    this.userService.getUser().subscribe(data=>{
      this.user=data;
    });
   }
}
```

[image: error doing what satanTime says]

```js
  saveUser(accessToken: string): void {
    let payload = this.getDataToken(accessToken);
    this._user = new User();
    this._user.id = payload.id;
    this._user.nameUser = payload.user_name;
    this._user.roles = payload.authorities;
    this._user.image=payload.image;
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this._user));
  }
```

```js
 public get user(): User {
    if (this._user != null) {
      return this._user;
    } else if (this._user == null && localStorage.getItem('user') != null) {
      this._user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')) as User;
      return this._user;
    }
    return new User();
  }
  public get token(): string {
    if (this._token != null) {
      return this._token;
    } else if (this._token == null && localStorage.getItem('token') != null) {
      this._token = localStorage.getItem('token');
      return this._token;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: might you explain how login is happening and when you want to rerender?

Comment: Don't post images of code and errors; post the code/errors themselves instead.

Comment: When I login, I save a user object in the SessionStorage and then navigate to another component, but since the header has been loaded before login, until the page refreshes, it does not request again, so it does not load the username and the image in the header

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `async` pipe instead of the `getUser()` method. Then it will listen on changes.

```js
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  user$;
  constructor(private authService:AuthService,private router:Router,private userService:UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.user$ = this.userService.getUser().pipe(share());
  }
}
```

and in the template

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="user$ | async as user">
 {{ user | json }}
</ng-container>
```

every time then the `userService.getUser()` updates the user the template will be rerendered.

Comment: Wouldn't doing this in OnInit be the better practice since it sort of blocks execution until the constructor is done and the field is initialized?

Comment: `getUser` is asynchronous and it doesn't block anything, that's why you need to subscribe to get is value.

Comment: There is still an execution of the call. The whole process of creating the request and sending it. By how the life time of angular and the classes that are created is done it is advisable to do this OnInit.

Comment: Oh boy, in this case it should be written in a totally different manner. The author of the question can decide how to use the code in his app. here it's just an example how to listen on changes of getUser and react on them.

Comment: Good it gives me an error when executing the new code and edited my question attaching a photo to it, thanks for the help

Comment: Okay, looks like there are some dependencies around, let's the setup later in the ngOnInit. I've updated the code.

Comment: I continue with the same error, you must call getUser on another site or because it still does not work. Answer in a comment above my way to login. Thank you very much for the help

Comment: Okay, this getUser won't work because it's static too due to localStorage dependency, might you share the code where you set the user to the localStorage?

Comment: Are they both in the same class? get and save

Comment: I have re-edited you mean this and if they are in the same service

Comment: yep, are they written under the same class like UserService?

Comment: They are not in another service called AuthService

Comment: Awesome, 1 min then

Comment: Which is the solution then?

Comment: Ah, didn't publish. I'll update it soon. The idea is to provide beside the service also an observable that emits on data change, then you can subscribe on it and it will be responsible for notifications about updates.

Comment: Thank you very much, I hope your answer.